# Different behavior between pdf_document and bookdown::pdf_document2 when using compareGroups

Tags: r, bookdown

I am having an issue when knit-ing documents using bookdown::pdf_document2 that don't appear when using the standard pdf_document.

Specifically, I am using the compareGroups library and the export2md function to output comparison tables such as the one shown below:

[image]

This is successful when I use `output:pdf_document`. However, The table is not properly created when I use `output: bookdown:pdf_document2`.[image]

There are clearly differences in the `tex` files and I am manually able to copy the table from the tex outputed by pdf_document to pdf_document2. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to get bookdown to correctly create the table? I have create a repo with my bug found here for more details: https://github.com/vitallish/bookdown-bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Overview

`bookdown::pdf_document2()` is different from `rmarkdwon::pdf_document()`, the former set `$opts_knit$kable.force.latex` to `TRUE` while the latter leaves that to default value (`FALSE`).

## check `.md` file

I think that the process from `.md` to `.tex` should be the same, and the difference in `.tex` files might due to the difference in `.md` files. So I run the following code to keep the intermediate `.md` files.

```
rmarkdown::render('pdf_document.Rmd', clean = FALSE)
file.remove('pdf_document.utf8.md');

rmarkdown::render('pdf_document2.Rmd', clean = FALSE)
file.remove('pdf_document2.utf8.md');
```

### `pdf_document.knit.md`

```
Table: Summary descriptives table by groups of `Sex'

Var                                               Male   N=1101    Female   N=1193    p.overall 
-----------------------------------------------  ---------------  -----------------  -----------
Recruitment year:                                                                       0.506   
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1995                       206 (18.7%)       225 (18.9%)                
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2000                       390 (35.4%)       396 (33.2%)                
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2005                       505 (45.9%)       572 (47.9%)                
Age                                                54.8 (11.1)       54.7 (11.0)        0.840   
Smoking status:                                                                        <0.001   
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Never smoker               301 (28.1%)       900 (77.5%)                
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Current or former < 1y     410 (38.3%)       183 (15.7%)                
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Former >= 1y               360 (33.6%)       79 (6.80%)                 
Systolic blood pressure                            134 (18.9)        129 (21.2)        <0.001   
Diastolic blood pressure                           81.7 (10.2)       77.8 (10.5)       <0.001
```

### `pdf2_document.knit.md`

```
\begin{table}

\caption{(\#tab:md-output)Summary descriptives table by groups of `Sex'}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|c|c|c}
\hline
Var & Male   N=1101 & Female   N=1193 & p.overall\\
\hline
Recruitment year: &  &  & 0.506\\
\hline
\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;1995 & 206 (18.7\%) & 225 (18.9\%) & \\
\hline
\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;2000 & 390 (35.4\%) & 396 (33.2\%) & \\
\hline
\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;2005 & 505 (45.9\%) & 572 (47.9\%) & \\
\hline
Age & 54.8 (11.1) & 54.7 (11.0) & 0.840\\
\hline
Smoking status: &  &  & <0.001\\
\hline
\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;Never smoker & 301 (28.1\%) & 900 (77.5\%) & \\
\hline
\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;Current or former < 1y & 410 (38.3\%) & 183 (15.7\%) & \\
\hline
\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;\&nbsp;Former >= 1y & 360 (33.6\%) & 79 (6.80\%) & \\
\hline
Systolic blood pressure & 134 (18.9) & 129 (21.2) & <0.001\\
\hline
Diastolic blood pressure & 81.7 (10.2) & 77.8 (10.5) & <0.001\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

That explains why you see different appearance in the pdf output.

## explore

To further explore the reason,

```
> pdf1 <- rmarkdown::pdf_document()
> pdf2 <- bookdown::pdf_document2()
> all.equal(pdf, pdf2)
[1] "Length mismatch: comparison on first 11 components"                                      
[2] "Component “knitr”: Component “opts_knit”: target is NULL, current is list"               
[3] "Component “pandoc”: Component “args”: Lengths (8, 12) differ (string compare on first 8)"
[4] "Component “pandoc”: Component “args”: 8 string mismatches"                               
[5] "Component “pandoc”: Component “ext”: target is NULL, current is character"               
[6] "Component “pre_processor”: target, current do not match when deparsed"                   
[7] "Component “post_processor”: target is NULL, current is function"
```

Since **knitr** convert Rmarkdown to pandoc markdown, I guess `$knitr` cause the difference in `.md` files.

```
> all.equal(pdf$knitr, pdf2$knitr)
[1] "Component “opts_knit”: target is NULL, current is list"

> pdf2$knitr$opts_knit
$bookdown.internal.label
[1] TRUE

$kable.force.latex
[1] TRUE
```

`kable` is a function to output table, so `$knitr$opts_knit$kable.force.latex` might to the root reason.

## verify

To test my assumption,

```
pdf3 <- pdf2
pdf3$knitr$opts_knit$kable.force.latex = FALSE
rmarkdown::render('pdf_document3.Rmd', clean = FALSE, output_format = pdf3)
file.remove('pdf_document3.utf8.md')
```

### `pdf_document3.knit.md`

```
Var                                               Male   N=1101    Female   N=1193    p.overall 
-----------------------------------------------  ---------------  -----------------  -----------
Recruitment year:                                                                       0.506   
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1995                       206 (18.7%)       225 (18.9%)                
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2000                       390 (35.4%)       396 (33.2%)                
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2005                       505 (45.9%)       572 (47.9%)                
Age                                                54.8 (11.1)       54.7 (11.0)        0.840   
Smoking status:                                                                        <0.001   
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Never smoker               301 (28.1%)       900 (77.5%)                
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Current or former < 1y     410 (38.3%)       183 (15.7%)                
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Former >= 1y               360 (33.6%)       79 (6.80%)                 
Systolic blood pressure                            134 (18.9)        129 (21.2)        <0.001   
Diastolic blood pressure                           81.7 (10.2)       77.8 (10.5)       <0.001
```

Wa oh!

## Advanced

Actually `compareGroups::export2md` use `knitr::kable` as the working horse,

```
> compareGroups::export2md
function (x, which.table = "descr", nmax = TRUE, header.labels = c(), 
    caption = NULL, ...) 
{
    if (!inherits(x, "createTable")) 
        stop("x must be of class 'createTable'")
    ...
    if (ww %in% c(1)) {
        ...
        table1 <- table1[-1, , drop = FALSE]
        return(knitr::kable(table1, align = align, row.names = FALSE, 
            caption = caption[1]))
    }
    if (ww %in% c(2)) {
        table2 <- prepare(x, nmax = nmax, c())[[2]]
        ...
        return(knitr::kable(table2, align = align, row.names = FALSE, 
            caption = caption[2]))
    }
}
```

which use `kable.force.latex` as an internal option to adjust its output. If your browse the GitHub repository of **knitr**, you can find the following code  in the `R/utils.R` file

```
kable = function(
  x, format, digits = getOption('digits'), row.names = NA, col.names = NA,
  align, caption = NULL, format.args = list(), escape = TRUE, ...
) {

  # determine the table format
  if (missing(format) || is.null(format)) format = getOption('knitr.table.format')
  if (is.null(format)) format = if (is.null(pandoc_to())) switch(
    out_format() %n% 'markdown',
    latex = 'latex', listings = 'latex', sweave = 'latex',
    html = 'html', markdown = 'markdown', rst = 'rst',
    stop('table format not implemented yet!')
  ) else if (isTRUE(opts_knit$get('kable.force.latex')) && is_latex_output()) {
    # force LaTeX table because Pandoc's longtable may not work well with floats
    # http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276699/9128
    'latex'
  } else 'pandoc'
  if (is.function(format)) format = format()
  ...
  structure(res, format = format, class = 'knitr_kable')
}
```

## Conclusion

`$knitr$opts_knit$kable.force.latex = TRUE` cause `bookdown::pdf_document2()` to insert latex code in the `.md` file, while `rmarkdown::pdf_document()` preserves the markdown code, which leaves pandoc the chance to give a pretty table.

I don't think this is a bug. Yihui Xie (the author of **bookdown**) might have some special reason to do this. And `bookdown::pdf_document2()` never need to be the same as `rmarkdown::pdf_document()`.

Comment: Excellent. This is very helpful. I appreciate you also showing me how you investigated the problem, I'll keep it in mind moving forward. One additional I want to make is that it looks like you can also set the knit option in the document itself with: `knitr::opts_knit$set(kable.force.latex=FALSE)` in the head of the code. It's weird cause it's not listed as an option in `opts_knit` but you can still set in document. I will see how this works and comment if I see any break in other functionality.

Comment: You're welcome. Your question is the first one I meet on Stack Overflow that is very clear and contains a reproducible example. So I decide to explore it (though it takes me a whole afternoon). Thank you so much for voting my answer up and accepting it. You can check what I add.

Answer (score 1):

This problem with **export2md** has been solved in the latest version of **compareGroups** package (4.0) available on github. You can install this newest version by typing:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("isubirana/compareGroups")
```

I hope this version will be submitted to CRAN very soon.